# Game crashes when trying to access function inside of a class, inside of a vector

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

So, I have a object, inside of a vector and I'm trying to call a function in that object :

```
std::vector<Box>entities;

entities.insert(entities.begin() +1, Box(&world, b2Vec2(Camera.getCenter().x, Camera.getCenter().y), b2Vec2(25, 25), 0, sf::Color::Red, b2_dynamicBody, 1.0f, 0.3));

window.draw(*entities[0].getSfShape());
```

But, my game crashes instantly with this error :

> Debug assertion failed!
>
> Program C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
>
> File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector
>
> Line: 159
>
> Experssion: vector iterator + offset out of range
>
> For more information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the visual c++ documentaion on asserts.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, at all. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::vector<Box>entities;

entities.insert(entities.begin() +1
```

You try to insert to `begin()+1`... but `begin()==end()` in an empty vector so you're essentially doing `end()+1` which is not ever a valid location.

That also explains the error message as the `begin()` is the only use of an iterator in your code, and the illegal offset being the `+1` that tries to increment the iterator past the end of the vector.

You should probably be using [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) or [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).